# Min max formulation conversion to max min formulation. Reason?

Tags: lagrange-multipliers, duality

Question is based on the screenshot attached. Based on paper [here](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=I3xhgVtNC5t).

[image]

**I am not being able to understand why min max formulation (eq 4) is first converted to max min formulation (eq 5). Is it something required to apply strong duality?
Also why is max min formulation (eq 5) again converted to min max formulation (eq 6)?**